# What effect does quality setting have for the Phonegap camera plugin for iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

For the 'quality' parameter in the Phonegap camera plugin, I understand the number ranges from 0 to 100. However, is there any resource showing in a rigorous way or has anyone examined how in practice this number actually changes the quality of the image or how it will correspond to actual image quality and file size for iOS apps? Any recommendations for how to optimize this number for keeping high quality but minimum file size so saving the image to a server is as fast as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, my image sizes must be less than 100 KB. I think you can't know the camera resolution, look cordova documentation:

> quality: Quality of the saved image, expressed as a range of 0-100, where 100 is typically full resolution with no loss from file compression. (Number) (Note that information about the camera's resolution is unavailable.)

But on ios you have a copy:

> When using destinationType.FILE_URI, photos are saved in the application's temporary directory. You may delete the contents of this directory using the navigator.fileMgr APIs if storage space is a concern.

I have tested several qualities but if the resolution camera is poor photos will be poor too.

Comment: Any idea on how to implement a minimum resolution check or something?  "Hey, your pictures are going to look like crap. We'd advise against uploading them."